# How to add font awesome icon dynamically to class elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While I'm using Bootstrap's alerts I wanted to add an icon next to alert content using jQuery for every element wth .alert class.

Example:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">Please log in to process</div>
```

and I want to add font awesome icon before alert content with following result:

```
<div class="alert alert-info"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>Please log in to process</div>
```

To perform this I've used jQuery prepend() function like this:

```
$('.alert-info').prepend('<i class="fas fas-info-circle"></i>');
```

but while debugging, it's seems like jQuery cannot find any element with `.alert-info` class, so the icon is not showing.
I guess this is some issue that DOM model is not loaded while browser executes above function, so I edited this snippet to wait for model:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.alert-info').prepend('<i class="fas fas-info-circle"></i>');
});
```

and icon code (`<i>` element) has been added, but just as an empty space without icon.

I had searched for any solution and I've found some info that font awesome is resolved `<i>` element and replace them with `<svg>` content while browser is rendering page, but I'm not sure if I correctly understand that mechanism(Source: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/jquery).

Is there any option to dynamically add font awesome icon using jQuery or I have to manually add icon to any alert content?

//edit

I've got my jQuery code in external file and I throught it could be the issue, but:

- I've put this code into  tag of page and icon was rendered correctly
- Copy this code into the same external file and now its work like harm, but now I cannot replicate previous issue, so still no clue, why it's not worked earlier...

Anyway, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: You code looks just fine, if you insert this `<i class="fas fas-info-circle"></i>` directly into your page, do you then see it`?

Comment: @Carsten yes, then it's works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly - make sure you have loaded both libraries correctly, and have waited for them to be requested and imported.

```js
$(() => {
  $(".alert-info").prepend(`<i class="fas fa-info-circle">`);
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-info">Please log in to process</div>
```